# Como mudar a cor do texto exibido no input no Python

Tags: python

no terminal do VSCode, usando o colorama, o texto do input é printado com a cor desejada, já nos outros terminais sai o código ANSI

```
import colorama
from colorama import Fore, Style

user_input = input(Fore.WHITE + Style.BRIGHT + 'Texto Do Input' + Fore.RESET)
```

saída:

```
←[37m←[1mTexto Do Input←[39m
```

teria alguma forma de mudar a cor do texto exibido no input?

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa chamar o [`init()`](https://github.com/tartley/colorama#initialisation) antes de usar o Colorama. Isso vai filtrar os códigos ANSI pelas chamadas corretas em cada plataforma.

```
import colorama
from colorama import Fore

colorama.init()
print(Fore.RED + 'vermelho!')
colorama.deinit()
```

Se isso não funcionar, tente forçar a opção convert na chamada do init. Por exemplo: `colorama.init(convert=True)`.